Jackson fails due FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS but feature is disabled
I'm trying to migrate my Spring Boot app from 3.0 to 3.3.
I have some complex JSON sent from the frontend so the ObjectMapper is configured like this
@Bean
public Module dateSerializationModule() {
    return new SimpleModule("dateFormat")
        .addDeserializer(Date.class, new MultiDateDeserializer()).addSerializer(Date.class, new DateSerializer());
}

@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper mapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper()
        .findAndRegisterModules().registerModule(attributesModule()).registerModule(dateSerializationModule())
        .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
        .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS, false)
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
}

The feature DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS is disabled by default and i tried to add it here, but i get this exception

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Trailing token (of type FIELD_NAME) found after value (bound as com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode): not allowed as per DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS
Caused by:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Trailing
token (of type FIELD_NAME) found after value (bound as
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode): not allowed as per
DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS  at [Source: REDACTED
(StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION disabled); line: 1,
column: 11847] (through reference chain:
my.dto.MyDTO["aDateField"])
at
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]     at
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportTrailingTokens(DeserializationContext.java:1840)
~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]     at
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._verifyNoTrailingTokens(ObjectMapper.java:5013)
~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]     at
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:4886)
~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]     at
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:3145)
~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]     at
my.app.MultiDateDeserializer.deserialize(MultiDateDeserializer.java:41)
~[main/:na]   at
my.app.MultiDateDeserializer.deserialize(MultiDateDeserializer.java:1)
~[main/:na]

And this is the MultiDateDeserializer where the exception is thrown
public class MultiDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Date> {
    public MultiDateDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public MultiDateDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);  // Exception thrown here
        // ...
    }
}

And the corresponding field on the json
aDateField: "2022-03-09T00:00:00.000"

I debugged to if my ObjectMapper bean and the ObjectMapper used when the exception is thrown is the same and it's the same object instance.
I tried to enable the feature (just for test) and debugged the featureFlags variable inside com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext but when true or false the value is the same.
I missed something or is it a bug inside jackson 2.17 ? was working with jackson 2.14 with the same input json

bug in jackson or invalid json? Unqoted field name is invalid....

do you mean that jackson recognize this as invalid after version upgrade as an official behavior change ?

Upgrading from jackson 2.17.1 to 2.17.2 solved the issue

This error still occurs for me and we're on Jackson 2.18.x

In our case we use Spring Boot + Jersey so latest version of Boot didn't work with latest version of this jersey jackson library.
We had to pin it to this 3.1.3 version:
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.3</version>
 </dependency>


This should be the accepted answer as it also resolved it for me.  There must be a bug in the latest version of jersey-media-json-jackson

Ran into a similar problem migrating spring:

Boot 3.2.5 -> 3.3.1
Cloud 2023.0.1 -> 2023.0.2

Specifically it appeared that WebClient was not picking up the customized Jackson primary bean.
Explicitly configuring our WebClient got us around the issue.
@Component
public class CustomClient {

  private final WebClient webClient;

  public CustomClient(String url, ObjectMapper mapper, WebClient.Builder builder) {
    this.webClient = builder.baseUrl(url)
                            .codecs(config -> config.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2Decoder(mapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)))
                            .build();

}

